# install_github doesn't work

Tags: r, github

I tried to download R package directly from github:

```
library(devtools)    
install_github("R-Websockets",username = "zeenogee")
```

however I always end up with an error:

```
Installing github repo(s) R-Websockets/master from zeenogee
Installing R-Websockets.zip from https://github.com/zeenogee/R-Websockets/archive/master.zip
Installing websockets
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.1/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:\Users\Steef\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpmc8IKG\R-Websockets-master"  \
  --library="C:/Users/Steef/Documents/R/win-library/3.0" --with-keep.source 

* installing *source* package 'websockets' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'websockets'
* removing 'C:/Users/Steef/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/websockets'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I know that the install works with Ubuntu but dont want to install Ubuntu just for installing one R package. Downloading the .zip file and isntalling locally also didn't work.
My R version is 3.0.1.

Anyone can help with installing that package? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have Rtools installed? What version? Is it in your path?

Comment: Installing Rtools solved that out! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing RTools solved that issue.