# Getting Timeout error when trying to install "BelgiumStatistics" R package from GitHub

Tags: r, github, timeout, install.packages

I have tried to install the newly released R package called "BelgiumStatistics". This package contains all the datasets released by Statistics Belgium (Bevolking, Werk, Leefmilieu, Census 2011). The related information to the data and the package is available through several links attached here:

[1. Open Data in Belgium - release of BelgiumStatistics R package](http://www.bnosac.be/index.php/blog/52-open-data-in-belgium-release-of-belgiumstatistics-r-package)

[2. Open Data of Belgium - provided at GitHub](https://github.com/jwijffels/BelgiumStatistics.git)

The problem is that I get a timeout error after doing exactly what the instruction says:

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("jwijffels/StatisticsBelgium", subdir ="BelgiumStatistics")
Downloading GitHub repo jwijffels/StatisticsBelgium@master
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
Timeout was reached
traceback()
13: .Call(R_curl_fetch_memory, url, handle)
12: curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle)
11: request_fetch.write_memory(req$output, req$url, handle)
10: request_fetch(req$output, req$url, handle)
9: request_perform(req, hu$handle$handle)
8: httr::HEAD(src_submodules, , auth)
7: github_has_remotes(x, auth)
6: remote_download.github_remote(remote, quiet = quiet)
5: remote_download(remote, quiet = quiet)
4: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
3: vapply(remotes, install_remote, ..., FUN.VALUE = logical(1))
2: install_remotes(remotes, ...)
1: devtools::install_github("jwijffels/StatisticsBelgium", subdir =   "BelgiumStatistics")
```

I have seen several issues discussed here, such as :

[install_github doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701121/install-github-doesnt-work?rq=1)

[Error while using install_github | devtools | timeout issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311872/error-while-using-install-github-devtools-timeout-issue#)

[Solution. How to install_github when there is a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783686/solution-how-to-install-github-when-there-is-a-proxy)

But they were not useful in my case, since I do not have any problems with proxy or downloading other packages for example from Cran . By the way, I am using RStudio (Version 0.99.486 ) with R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) installed on Windows 7 and I have the latest version of Rtools installed (Rtools33).

I wonder that whether it is the problem of this package which has about 100MB or the GitHub itself. I downloaded the package from GitHub and I tried to install the package from zip file or even pasting it directly to the place that I have all the other libraries installed (i.e. C:\Users\xxx\Documents\R\win-library) but it failed too. So, What could be the solution?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error with Linux.